# Use Google Maps restricted API key on server side ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-core, google-maps-api-3

I have an application in production that uses lots of Google Maps services and therefore I've created a restricted API key with `HTTP referrers` restriction. The restricted key works fine sending requests from client (loading maps, etc.), but I have trouble using it server side as I send some of the requests from ASP.NET Core controllers. Before I send the request I set the `Referer` header, but still the request gets denied:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Referrer = new Uri(_configuration.GetValue<string>("Google:RequestReferrer")); //referrer string is set in the appsettings.json file
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Is it possible to use the same restricted key on client side and server side by somehow setting the correct request headers or should I create a new API key restricted with IP for the server side usage.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried restricting the key by IP address instead of HTTP Referrer?

Comment: My idea is to use the same key on client and server side. If I restrict it with IP, I guess I won't be able to use it on client side. Anyway, I shall try to use the IP restricted key on server side just to make sure it works.

Comment: The referrer is based on the hostname of the server making the call, not a header you arbitrarily set. Think about it: if you could just set a header, then the referrer filtering would be pointless. Any old app on any old server could just pretend they're you and use your restricted key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you're going to make 2 different types of requests (client side and server side) you should have a separate API key restricted with HTTP referrers for the client side, and an API key restricted with IP addresses for the server side.

You may also visit the API key Best Practices [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices?authuser=0#restrict_apikey) for more details.